# RxJs lookup data from one array and map into another

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an angular project that's modeled after a simple eCommerce use case with Orders and Products. I have both an Order service that returns a list of `Order` objects. That interface looks something like this:

```js
export interface Order {
  id: string;
  products: OrderProduct[];
}
```

`OrderProduct`s look like this:

```js
export interface OrderProduct {
  productId: string;
  quantity: number;
  price: number;
}
```

The last interface that's worth noting is my `Product`, which has the `name` field that I'm interested in. It looks like this:

```js
export interface Product {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  price: number;
}
```

Now back in Angular, when I get into my `OrderDetail` component, I want to generate a little receipt or invoice, that shows the line items (aka `OrderProducts`) with the actual product name, and not just the ID. In order to do so, I have to look up the product from the `ProductService`. I'd like not to make a separate service call for each Product. Instead, I'd rather grab all products, and just have them in memory, then when I'm iterating over my Order's OrderProducts, just expand that object to include the Product's name, as looked up from my local `allProducts$` observable array. Here's a snippet of what I'm working with:

```js
  orderProducts$: Observable<OrderProduct[]> | undefined;
  allProducts$: Observable<Product[]> | undefined;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private orderSvc: OrdersService,
    private productSvc: ProductService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.orderId$ = this.route.params.pipe(map((o) => o['orderId']));
    this.order$ = this.orderId$.pipe(switchMap((o) => this.orderSvc.get(o)));
    this.orderProducts$ = this.order$.pipe(map((o) => o.products));
    this.allProducts$ = this.productSvc.fetch();
  }
```

Notice I have all of my products in the `allProducts$` observable. What I'm looking looking to do, is create another observable that somehow marries up the associated product from the `allProducts$` observable with the current `orderProduct` from the `orderProducts$` observable, and expands it to include the Product's name (which, again, is only available in the `allProducts$` observable.

If I were doing this in plain js (or ts), I'd be doing something like this:

```js
const productsWithName = order.products.map(op => {
    const product = allProducts.find(p => p.id === op.productId);
    return {
        ...op,
        name: product?.name || '',
    }
});
```

Now my `productsWithName` array has everything I'd need. Ideally I could get that same array, as an observable array, without ever leaving Observable-land (i.e. I don't want to have to unwrap my observable to mess with them as standard JS arrays). I've tried various permutations of this with RxJs operators, but can't figure it out. I feel like I'm missing something stupid, but would appreciate a kickstart. Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `combineLatest` may solve this problem.

```
combineLatest([this.order$, this.allProducts$)).pipe(
  filter(([order, allProducts]) => !!order && !!allProducts),
  map(([order, allProducts]) => {
    return order.products.map(op => {
      const product = allProducts.find(p => p.id === op.productId);
      return {
        ...op,
        name: product?.name || '',
      }
    }) 
  }) 
)
```

We can subscribe the latest value of both `order$` and `allProducts$` and do your mapping logic inside a `map` operator. The `filter` filters out the initial `undefined` values.

Comment: This works! Thanks! Here's a [blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-bcixnc?file=index.ts) that implements your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

1. `concat` two Observable
2. `groupBy` productId or id
3. `o$` -> use `reduce` combined data

```
const orderProducts: Array<OrderProduct> = [
  { productId: '3', quantity: 2, price: 30 },
  { productId: '1', quantity: 1, price: 150 },
  { productId: '2', quantity: 9, price: 10 },
];
const allProducts: Array<Product> = [
  { id: '1', name: 'Apple', price: 30 },
  { id: '2', name: 'Banana', price: 150 },
  { id: '3', name: 'Cherry', price: 10 },
];

const orderProducts$ = from(orderProducts);
const allProducts$ = from(allProducts);

concat(orderProducts$, allProducts$).pipe(
  groupBy((k) => 'productId' in k ? k.productId : k.id),
  mergeMap((o$) => o$.pipe(reduce((a,c) => ({...a, ...c})))),
  toArray()
).subscribe(...);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-teu64g

Comment: thanks for this. The code is concise and DRY (even if I can't completely reason about how it's working), however it doesn't quite do what I was hoping. If I remove an entry from the `orderProducts`, I still get 3 entries in the output. My hope is to get just the products in the `orderProducts` array expanded to include the correlated name from `allProducts`. Hope that makes sense. Here's a forked blitz that demonstrates what I'm saying: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-py7tyc?file=index.ts